# Using Python's Format Specification Mini-Language to print spaces with variables

Tags: python

I try to print to print a space with Specification Mini-Language with using variables.

for example:

instead of this

```py
print('{:>10}'.format('hello'))
```

I want do this:

```py
i = 10
print('{:>i}'.format('hello'))
```

I get this error:

> ValueError: Unknown format code 'i' for object of type 'str'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could do it like this:

```
print(('{:>' + str(i) +'}').format('hello'))
```

Answer (score 2):

Put `i` in brackets and add it to the format arguments like this:

```
i = 10
print('{:>{i}}'.format('hello', i=i))
#      hello
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own format string like this:

```
i = 10
format_string = '{:>' + str(i) + '}'
print(format_string .format('hello'))
```